# Добавить поле к существующему классу (Attached Properties)

Tags: c#

Есть класс Line c полями Begin, End.
Теперь нужно чтобы у класса Line была толщина.
Реализую с помощью методов расширения GetDepth и SetDepth.
Как это можно сделать?

```
namespace Geometry   
{
    public class Line
    {
        public Point Begin;
        public Point End;
    }
} 

namespace GeometryPaint
{
    public static class SegmentExtension
    {
        public static int GetDepth (this Line line)
           {
               //TODO
           }
        public static void SetDepth (this Line line, int depth)
           {
               //TODO
           }
    }

    public static class SegmentExtension
    {
        static void Main()
           {
               var lineOne = new Line { Begin = new Point(0,0), End = new Point(3,3)};
               var lineTwo = new Line { Begin = new Point(4,2), End = new Point(7,9)};
               lineOne.SetDepth(5);
               lineTwo.SetDepth(32);
               int depthLineTwo = lineTwo.GetDepth();
               int depthLineOne = lineOne.GetDepth();
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну так и добавьте в класс Line Depth. В текущем виде GetDepth нельзя никак вычислить по координатам точек начала и конца.

Comment: Непонятно зачем только это понадобилось, используйте обычные свойства `{ get; set; }`

Comment: `new Point {0,0}` -странная запись, у вас `Point` представляет собой массив что ли?

Comment: @Андрей да действительно опечатка new Point(1,1);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

То, что вы хотите, называется Attached Properties. В C# нет родного (на уровне синтаксиса) механизма их реализации. Но в стандартной библиотеке есть класс [`ConditionalWeakTable<TKey, TValue>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx), который позволяет хранить значения "дополнительных" свойств, не продлевая при этом жизнь объектов-ключей. Реализация attached properties через него будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Geometry
{
    public static class SegmentExtensions
    {
        // TValue должен быть reference type, так что костыль в виде каста к object
        private readonly static ConditionalWeakTable<Line, object> _depthValues =
            new ConditionalWeakTable<Line, object>();

        public static int GetDepth(this Line line)
        {
            return (int)_depthValues.GetValue(line, (l) => 0);
        }
        public static void SetDepth(this Line line, int depth)
        {
            _depthValues.Remove(line);
            // возможно, затрайкетчить в случае работы из нескольких потоков
            _depthValues.Add(line, depth);
        }
    }

    public static class Startup
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var lineOne = new Line { Begin = new Point ( 0, 0 ), End = new Point ( 3, 3 ) };
            var lineTwo = new Line { Begin = new Point ( 4, 2 ), End = new Point ( 7, 9 ) };
            lineOne.SetDepth(5);
            lineTwo.SetDepth(32);
            int depthLineTwo = lineTwo.GetDepth();
            int depthLineOne = lineOne.GetDepth();
        }
    }

    public class Line
    {
        public Point Begin;
        public Point End;
    }

    public class Point
    {
        private int v1;
        private int v2;

        public Point(int v1, int v2)
        {
            this.v1 = v1;
            this.v2 = v2;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: а в wpf это разве не на уровне языка сделано?

Comment: @Grundy на уровне языка, но только языка xaml + работает нормально только для наследников System.Windows.DependencyObject

Comment: А в чём собственно их выгода по сравнению с обычными свойствами? Можете раскрыть подробнее?

Comment: @AK в том, что это способ прицепить свойство к уже существующему классу (вообще любому, даже из сторонней библиотеки). В WPF это позволяет, например, прицепить ко всем контролам свойства с именами Grid.Column, Grid.Row. И указывать в разметке, где именно в гриде лежит какой-нибудь Button, без вписывания этих свойств в класс Button или Control

Comment: @AK т.е. это такое развитие идеи Extension Methods, но с возможностью прицепить не только функционал, но и значения

Comment: @PashaPash, Огромное спасибо! Именно это и нужно! Сейчас разберусь с ConditionalWeakTable.

Comment: @PashaPash, если не сложно объясни пожалуйста один момент, второй аргумент в GetValue "(l) => 0".
Это значит, что при отсутствии нужного ключа, ключ создаваться не будет? Верно?

Comment: @Данила, это значит, что если такого ключа не существует, то он будет создан со значением 0: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd413870.aspx

Comment: @Данила да, ключ создаваться не будет - т.е. значение вернется назад, но в таблицу сохранено не будет. GetOrCreateValue и создаст значение, и сохранит его в таблицу